# In a RecyclerView what is the difference between scrollToPosition and smoothScrollToPosition?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I have a doubt with the RecyclerView scroll. In a RecyclerView what is the difference between scrollToPosition and smoothScrollToPosition?

Comment: Its in the name . `scrollToPosition` will directly jump to position specified without any scrolling effect and other one does it with scrolling effect check [definition](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#scrollToPosition(int)).

Comment: @ADM Very good explanation.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smoothScrollToPosition will perform a smooth to the adapter item position, and in contrast scrollToPosition will jump to the position of the adapter item without performing a smooth scroll.